# Could a woman have been a priest in the Temple back in the time of David, and if not, why not?

Tags: women, kohen-priest

Could a woman have been a priest in the Temple back in the time of David, and if not, why not?

Comment: It's usually called the Tabernacle, not the Temple, by the way.

Comment: Close-voters: I don't think that http://yodeya.com/q/44985 is relevant here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The Torah specifies that Aaron and his SONS are invested with the Priesthood ([Ex 29,9](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.29.9?lang=he-en)). While there are specific duties and rights incumbent on a Bat Kohen, a woman could not function as a Priest in the Temple.

Comment: Another thing..why are there no women priest,do you know why?

Comment: How do you know that that word means "sons" and not "children"? Afaik it can mean either, depending on context.

Comment: @msh210 Sure, but Aaron had only sons. So either way, it is talking about sons. (i.e Bereshit 7:7)

Comment: @AleksandrSigalov What about granddaughters? (How do you know he didn't have daughters too?)

Comment: @DoubleAA and if he'd have daughter it would say it just like with Dinah.

Comment: @AleksandrSigalov So you think that Yaakov had 63 grandsons and one granddaughter (as listed in Gen 46)? The chance of that are 1 in 3*10^18. Clearly daughters aren't always listed.

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree that Torah does not always mention women but in cases of patriarch genealogy seem to be complete. So yes, I believe that Jacob had only 1 daughter because Torah says so. This is the best argument for me. ;)

Comment: @DoubleAA http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13243 ... but I think we need to clean up the comments here.